# Only show Active Directory OU that contain User Accounts

Tags: vb.net, winforms, directoryservices

I can easily get a list of OU's from our Domain's AD but I only want to grab OU's with user accounts.

I am currently grabbing the list of OU's, and then going through each one to get the list of users and the count but it can take about 30 seconds to process all of that data.

I was hoping there was some quicker way to accomplish the same task.

```
Public Sub GetActiveDirectoryOuList()
    Dim de As DirectoryEntry = Nothing
    Dim ds As DirectorySearcher = Nothing
    Dim results As SearchResultCollection = Nothing

    Try
        de = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=csileasing,DC=com")
        ds = New DirectorySearcher(de, "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)")
        results = ds.FindAll

        If results.Count = 0 Then Exit Try

        For Each result As SearchResult In results
            Dim count As Integer = GetUserCountForOU(result.Properties("distinguishedName")(0).ToString)
            If count > 0 Then
                Dim ou As New OrgUnitInfo
                ou.DistinguisedName = result.Properties("distinguishedName")(0).ToString
                ou.Name = result.Properties("name")(0).ToString
                ou.UsersCount = count
                adOrgUnitList.Add(ou)
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If ds IsNot Nothing Then ds.Dispose()
        If de IsNot Nothing Then de.Dispose()
        If results IsNot Nothing Then results.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You can cache the result somewhere and invalidate the cache on a specific schedule or based on a specific request to invalidate the cache. Then when you need to get information, read from cache.

Comment: Is there a way to get the user count for an OU without reading in the full list of users and then doing a count?

The reading of all of the users from each of the OU's in AD is the part that taking forever.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure my DirectorySearcher operations are asking for the least amount of data possible. In your search for OU only specify the parameters you'll want to use, as such

```
ds = New DirectorySearcher(de, "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)", {"distinguishedName", "name"})
```

Also maybe try to do the same for your GetUserCountForOU method, if it is searching for all users with all their properties then it is entirely normal for it to take that long. You could specify an empty `PropertiesToLoad` array with a `Filter="(&(objectClass=user)(!objectClass=computer))"`and the `DirectorySearcher` will only look up the `objectGuid` (If I remember this correctly). You'd just have to count the resulting entries to get your `ou.UsersCount`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Masma.  I'll give it a try when I get back to this project.